# How do I add a main domain to my new hostgator hosting account?

Tags: web-hosting, domain-transfer

I have a domain which is with different account and I want to use this domain as a main domain for my new hosting account.

How do I do that?

Comment: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/transferring-a-domain-vs-changing-name-servers

Answer (score 1):

You will have to either get Hostgator to move it to your new account or you will have to delete it from the original account.

A domain can't be in DNS more than once in a hosting service.